# Where to find state-of-the-art time series data deep learning approaches?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

Just like [this](http://rodrigob.github.io/are_we_there_yet/build/#datasets) (which stopped updating) that shows the newest deep learning methods utilized in image recognition, is there some similar lists/summaries (in blog posts/paper/competitions etc.) about newest deep learning methods used in time series analysis?

Comment: I usually visit https://machinelearningmastery.com/  it talks more about time series analysis

Comment: There's no way anyone can answer this.(in an ever growing field). And you have no rights to call them idiots until you include yourself too..... If you want the latest trends, i hope you can search Google..

Answer (score 2):

There is an archive of papers related to time series analysis at [Arxiv Sanity Preserver](http://www.arxiv-sanity.com/search?q=time-series) which you may find useful. Among the many papers listed there are some which deal with deep learning approaches to time series.